# Last parameter must be of type Callback<X> or Callback<? super X>

Tags: android, android-studio, callback, retrofit, runtimeexception

I am using Proguard and it looks like this:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit.http.** <methods>;
}

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

Whenever I run app crashes and Log says:

```
Last parameter must be of type Callback<X> or Callback<? super X>
```

[Here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/372) I found discussion on same topic, but don't know where I am doing mistake ?

Comment: Please post some code with more details on what you are trying to do.

Comment: The answer to your question is this. `Last parameter must be of type Callback<X> or Callback<? super X>.`

Comment: @Aizen I found this link: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/372 and here is what my proguard looks like: http://pastebin.com/7pSuL9LM

Comment: `-keepattributes Signature


# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
`